Firebase deployment of a kotlin multiplatform js target is always showing SIte not found page
We have a kmm js target project, that we aim to server using Firebase hosting.
The firebase json for our deployment is
 {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/js/packages/MyApp-KMP-composeApp/kotlin",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json"
    ]
  }
 }

The index.html that our build produces is in the build/js/packages/MyApp-KMP-composeApp/kotlin, once I run firebsae deploy, I get a success deployment message and the Site Not Found.
The build directory after we run gradle jsBrowserProductionWebpack is
.
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── packages
├── packages_imported
└── yarn.lock

and inside package we have
├── kotlin
├── node_modules
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js

I am running the firebase deploy command from the root of my kotlin project.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong here?
